# iot_v1.types.FieldMask() How did it come？

Tags: google-cloud-iot

code:

```py
device_path = client.device_path(
        project_id, cloud_region, registry_id, device_id)
    mask = iot_v1.types.FieldMask()
    mask.paths.append('config')
    mask.paths.append('gateway_config')
    device = client.get_device(client.list_devices(parent=path, field_mask=mask))
```

Where does this FieldMask come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field mask is: `The fields of the Device resource to be returned in the response. The fields id and num_id are always returned, along with any other fields specified.` [Source](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iot/latest/v1.DeviceManagerClient.html#listDevices).

It comes from the [defined protobuf types](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iot/latest/google.protobuf.html#.FieldMask), which is part of the IoT package.